# can somebody tell me the method for sms normalization with python

Tags: python, sms, nlp, normalization

I am trying to do sms normalization with the help of python

suppose the request is "btw m gng home"
It should translate it into "by the way I am going home"

Can somebody tell me some logic for this which I can apply. Can I use NLP for the same purpose.If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a dictionary of short cuts that you wish to translate, split your message, replace any matches in the dictionary and join.

Comment: did that..but it doesnt always replaces the words..U cant predict every word

Comment: If you can't then how the heck can you expect your computer to!

Comment: u need to program the computer to do that...dont u know tha

Comment: The computer is a very fast moron - the programmer needs to be smart.